# Getting a Perl command output into a shell variable

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I'm a bit of a noob with Perl, and can't to see what's wrong with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
randAnPass=true;
if [ $randAnPass = true ]
then
pass=perl /root/bin/randpass
else
# prompt for setting user's password ..
echo -n "pick password for '${user}': "
read pass
fi
#echo $randAnPass;
echo "Generated pass = $pass";
```

For some reason it outputs:

```
r4Nd0mP
Generated pass =
```

I want it to output

```
Generated pass = r4Nd0mP
```

Comment: Use backticks to capture command output, you're just running the command.

Comment: @Dave: Backticks? `$()` is much better.

Comment: I don't see how it can be *much* better, but sure, that works too.

Comment: That worked :D probably should've been an answer lol cause.. well it is the answer :P. Thanks very much. :)

Comment: @DaveNewton - I am not sure of the benefits, so I asked :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-bash

Comment: @dvk I think backticks screw up more, but for simple usecases, I'll be interested to see if I should care-thanks for asking.

Comment: @Dave - my suspicions were correct, the only margin in usage is nesting which requires evil-looking escaping for backticks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pass=`perl /root/bin/randpass`
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to **just capture STDOUT** of perl command use,

```
pass=$(perl /root/bin/randpass)
```

But if you need to **capture both STDERR and STDOUT**,

```
pass=$(perl /root/bin/randpass 2>&1)
```