# What does $() do?

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to troubleshoot this issue:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128894/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host-not-using-hosts-d

and part of one solution is to use:

```
$(which sshd)
```

which in my case outputs:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

I keep a cheat sheet for all my bash commands and wanted to add in:

```
$()
```

It appears to be doing something to the sshd executable.

Related

[What does it mean in shell when we put a command inside dollar sign and parentheses: $(command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984958/what-does-it-mean-in-shell-when-we-put-a-command-inside-dollar-sign-and-parenthe)

Comment: That's a bad suggestion on the linked page. There's almost no reason at all for that over just `sshd` there. Also using `which` instead of `type` is poor (though common).

Comment: what is better about type ?

Comment: It is a shell built-in that is guaranteed to exist and has POSIX-specified behavior. `which` is none of those things.

Comment: @EtanReisner The linked answer explains why it recommended this and why simply using `sshd` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Random832 That reason doesn't cover not using `type` though it does cover not just using `sshd`.

Comment: @EtanReisner: You don't want to use `type` in scripting, it's output aim for interactive use instead of scripting. POSIXly, you need `command -v sshd`.

Comment: @cuonglm Yeah, `command -v` also works here and is better (I'm still converting my muscle memory from `type -p` to `command -v`).

Answer (score 3):

`$()` is a way to execute another process and collect its output. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst for more details.

When such expression is passed to bash, *its output* gets executed. It effectively call the command using its full path, as that is what `which` returns. The messages printed are from sshd process started by that expression.

Note that `which` locates executable scanning `$PATH`, same as when you execute the command. In other words, executing `which` output it is not going to affect which executable is run, only the full path to executable tracked by operating system.

Comment: It is worth noting that the command should execute regardless since `which` only knows to look in the same `PATH` that `bash` would use.  You get the same set of commands to run either way.  So the only effect of the `$(which foo)` should be that you can see the whole path to in `ps` or `top`.

Answer (score 0):

`$(which sshd)` will be replaced by *the stdout resulting from* running `which sshd`. `which sshd` will return the fully-qualified path of the executable invoked when invoking `sshd`:

> `which`  returns  the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed in the current environment, had its arguments been
>          given as commands in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching the `PATH` for executable  files  matching  the
>          names of the arguments. It does not follow symbolic links.

Examples, as run on a command line, where `>` represents the input prompt:

```
COMMAND: which sshd
 OUTPUT: /usr/sbin/sshd

COMMAND: echo "The full path of sshd is $(which sshd)"
 OUTPUT: The full path of sshd is /usr/sbin/sshd

COMMAND: $(which sshd)
 OUTPUT: [[whatever output you get from running /usr/sbin/sshd]]
```