# How to store the length of a string in a variable in bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell, scripting

I am using this [guide](https://www.shellhacks.com/bash-string-length/) as a reference.

I am able to run the command to find the length of a string, say

```
expr length 'monkey brains'
```

which returns 13 as expected

However I am having trouble with storing the result in a variable, say a variable called hi. First I tried straight up assigning hi

```
hi=expr length 'monkey brains'
```

which gave a command not found error.
My thought process was then to wrap the command all in a string and then use [$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984958/what-does-it-mean-in-shell-when-we-put-a-command-inside-dollar-sign-and-parenthe) to evaluate the string. So what I have is

```
hi="expr length 'monkey brains'"
echo $($hi)
```

but this didn't work either - expr: syntax error

Does anyone know what else I could try here or why my approach doesn't work?

Comment: Scroll down in the article. It explains how to assign the length.

Comment: have a look at this http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution as well

Comment: Since it is bash, why not `a="some string"; len=${#a}; echo "len: $len"`? Or, simply `a="some string"; echo "len: ${#a}"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
$ expr length 'monkey brains'
13
```

To store the output to a variable using *command substitution*:

```
$ len=$(expr length 'monkey brains'); echo "$len"
13
```

You can also do this using *parameter expansion* in bash:

```
$ string='monkey brains'; len=${#string}; echo "$len"
13
```

Both the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) and the [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters) are good resources for information.

Comment: Note for mac os x users, the 3rd option `len=${#string}` was working.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
hi="monkey brains"
echo -n $hi | wc -c
```

Comment: i know how to output it. This doesn't assign the value