# npm script : What is $

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to NPM and inherited a project which has the following line

```
"compile:clean": "$(cd ..; npm bin)/rimraf lib",
```

This works fine on mac and ubuntu but on windows when I run

```
npm run compile
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Command failed: npm run compile
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "compile:clean"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

What is `$` or what package I need to install on windows to recognize `$`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean in shell when we put a command inside dollar sign and parentheses: $(command)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984958/what-does-it-mean-in-shell-when-we-put-a-command-inside-dollar-sign-and-parenthe)

Comment: In short: that command is for bash, not for windows cmd.

Comment: I guess I have to rewrite the script if I need to make it work on windows or is there a package I can install to make it work?

Comment: You can run bash on windows.