# When we place $ before variable in bash shell - and when not?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to linux and trying to understand in what case we place $ before variables in shell, and when we don't.

```
myVar=5
echo $myVar            # use $
myVar=$((myVar+1))     # why not myVar = ($myVar+1)
export myVar           # don't use $ ?
unset myVar            # don't use $ ?
```

It's seems kind of inconsistent. Do you know some general rule, where we place $ before the variable, and when we don't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163144/608639), [What does it mean in shell when we put a command inside dollar sign and parentheses: $(command)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17984958/608639), etc.

Comment: Basically: If you want to assign content to a variable, use `variable`. If you want to access its content, use `$variable`.

Comment: the question is not about special shell variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Principle:

- Use `varName` if you want the variable itself (`export`, `unset`)

  - Special case: Arithmetic expansion `((expr))` and `$((expr))` accepts variables that contain numeric values
- Use `$varName` if you want the *value* or *content* that the variable holds (`if`, `for`, `case $var in`)

Answer (score 1):

`$` is used to expand a variable with its value, in an arithmetic expression the `$` is implicit because a word will be coerced to an integer value.

```
myVar=$((myVar+1))
# could also be written
myVar=$(($myVar+1))
# or
((myVar=$myVar+1))
((myVar=myVar+1))
((myVar+=1))
((++myVar))
# because variable assignment can be done in an arithmetic expression
```

`export` and `unset` are builtins but as expansion is performed before call, they can't be called like `unset $myVar` because myVar would be changed to its value.

For more details Bash manual, particularly the [basic features](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Basic-Shell-Features.html#Basic-Shell-Features),
[shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions), [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).