# Using xargs parameterrs as variables to compare two md5sum

Tags: bash, cut, xargs, md5sum, one-liner

I'm extracting two md5sums by using this code:

```
md5sum test{1,2} | cut -d' ' -f1-2
```

I'm receiving two md5sums as in example below:

```
02eace9cb4b99519b49d50b3e44ecebc 
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249
```

Afterwards I'm not sure how to compare them. I have tried using the xargs:

```
md5sum test{1,2} | cut -d' ' -f1-2 | xargs bash -c '$0 == $1'
```

However, it tries to execute md5sum as a command

Any advice?

Comment: Please add your desired output.

Comment: I have used this code:
`md5sum test{1,2} | cut -d' ' -f1-2 | xargs bash -c 'diff -u <(echo "$0") <(echo "$1")'`

However it only provide output when files differ...

Comment: You know about the `diff` command right?

Comment: @Cyrus I would like to get info that the two strings are exactly the same.
Something like "Equal".

Please note I'm trying to make it as one liner without using sed and awk.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [command subsitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984958/what-does-it-mean-in-shell-when-we-put-a-command-inside-dollar-sign-and-parenthe) instead

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo 1 > file_a
echo 2 > file_b
echo 1 > file_c

file1=file_a
# try doing "file2=file_b" as well
file2=file_c

if [[ $(sha1sum $file1 | cut -d ' ' -f1-2) = $(sha1sum $file2 | cut -d ' ' -f1-2) ]]; then
    echo same
else
    echo different
fi
```

Comment: I just added the echo statement after &&:
`md5sum test{1,3} | cut -d' ' -f1-2 | xargs bash -c 'diff -u <(echo "$0") <(echo "$1") && echo Success'`

However it's not so clean...

Additionally i would like to compare without creating new files.