# Bash Script - Integer expression expected

Tags: bash

With the below code, I keeping getting:
line 9: [: 8.8.8.8: integer expression expected
Unsure Why?

```
#!/bin/bash
sourceFile="file.log"
targetFile="2file.log"
ping="8.8.8.8"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 echo "$line" >> "$targetFile"
 sudo service networking restart
 ping -q -c 5 "$ping"
 if [ "$ping" -ne 0 ]; then
    sed -n -e 8p "$2file.log"
 fi
done < "$sourceFile"
```

Comment: Check your test against 0 (zero)

Comment: You appear to want to check the *exit status* of the previous command against 0, not the value of `$ping`: `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then` or more directly `if ! ping -q -c 5 "$ping"; then`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to compare "8.8.8.8" (string) to 0 (integer)

```
ping="8.8.8.8"
if [ "$ping" -ne 0 ]; then
```

ping variable is string.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string value (`"8.8.8.8"`) to an integer value (`0`)

You can retrieve the exit code of your `ping` command with `$?`

```
ping="8.8.8.8"

ping -q -c 5 "$ping"

ping=$?

if [ $ping -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "NOTOK"
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123211/checking-host-availability-by-using-ping-in-bash-scripts)

Comment: Or `if ping -q -c 5 "$ping"; then echo "OK"; else echo "NOTOK"; fi`