# Pipe output to environment variable export command

Tags: sh

I'm trying to set a git hash value into an environment variable, i thought it would be as simple as doing this:

```
git log --oneline -1 | export GIT_HASH=$1
```

But the `$1` doesn't contain anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`$1` is used to access the first argument in a script or a function.  It is not used to access output from an earlier command in a pipeline.

You can use [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) to get the output of the `git` command into an environment variable like this:

```
GIT_HASH=`git log --oneline -1` && export GIT_HASH
```

*However...*

This answer is specially in response to the question regarding the **Bourne Shell** and it is the most widely supported. Your shell (e.g. GNU Bash) will most likely support the `$()` syntax and so you should also consider Michael Rush's answer.

But some shells, like `tcsh`, do not support the `$()` syntax and so if you're writing a shell script to be as bulletproof as possible for the greatest number of systems then you should use the ``` `` ``` syntax despite the limitations.

Comment: For those who care the `export EMR_CLUSTER_ID_HELPER=\`cat /mnt/var/lib/info/job-flow.json | jq -r ".jobFlowId"\`` command works on Amazon EC2-Instance. I just tried it out to use for myself to so that I could put the EMR Cluster ID into an environment variable. So use the `` they work well. Thanks Don Cruickshank

Comment: In case of `git log --oneline -1` failure, `export GIT_HASH=...` **will not fail**.
In some cases it may lead to bugs hard to spot (i.e. CI/CD pipeline execution).
I would suggest following modification
`GIT_HASH=$(git log --oneline -1) && export GIT_HASH=$GIT_HASH`

Answer (score 52):

Or, you can also do it using $(). (see [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts))

For example:

```
export FOO_BACKWARDS=$(echo 'foo' | rev)
```

Comment: Plays nice with JQ - ```export USERNAME=$(mlr --c2j --jlistwrap cat ../../creds.csv | jq '.[0] | ."username"')```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an external file as a temporary variable:

```
TMPFILE=/var/tmp/mark-unsworth-bashvar-1
git log --oneline -1  >$TMPFILE; export GIT_HASH=$(cat $TMPFILE); rm $TMPFILE
echo GIT_HASH is $GIT_HASH
```