# Passing Bash Command Through SSH - Executing Variable Capture

Tags: bash, ssh

I am passing the following command straight through SSH:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /key/path server@111.111.111.111 'bash -s' << EOF
FPM_EXISTS=`ps aux | grep php-fpm`
if [ ! -z "$FPM_EXISTS" ]
then
        echo "" | sudo -S service php5-fpm reload
fi
EOF
```

I get the following error:

```
[2015-02-25 22:45:23] local.INFO: bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: line 1: ` FPM_EXISTS=root      2378  0.0  0.9 342792 18692 ?        Ss   17:41   0:04 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
```

It's like it is trying to execute the output of `ps aux | grep php-fpm` instead of just capturing git the variable. So, if I change the command to try to capture `ls`, it acts like it tries to execute that as well, of course returning "command not found" for each directory.

If I just paste the contents of the Bash script into a file and run it it works fine; however, I can't seem to figure out how to pass it through SSH.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap starting `EOF` in single quotes. Otherwise `ps aux | grep php-fpm` would get interpreted by the local shell.

The command should look like this:

```
ssh ... server@111.111.111.111 'bash -s' << 'EOF'
FPM_EXISTS=$(ps aux | grep php-fpm)
if [ ! -z "$FPM_EXISTS" ]
then
        echo "" | sudo -S service php5-fpm reload
fi
EOF
```

Check this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html (Section 19.7)

---

Btw, I would encourage you to use `$()` instead of backticks consequently for command substitution because of the ability to nest them. You will have more fun, believe me. Check this for example: [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap the `EOF` in single quotes.

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /key/path server@111.111.111.111 'bash -s' << 'EOF'
FPM_EXISTS=`ps aux | grep php-fpm`
if [ ! -z "$FPM_EXISTS" ]
then
        echo "" | sudo -S service php5-fpm reload
fi
EOF
```

Comment: Wondering what makes out the difference compared to my answer? (Except the missing explanation)

Comment: The time of posting. (Eh, nevermind - but it was nearly the same time. ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl, sorry my friend. At the time I started writing & testing my answer, I didn't see that you had already written something.

Comment: also it is not a "race". however, I really saw guys copying posts... sorry for blaming you! +1 nice answer ;)