# Abort bash script using a function

Tags: bash, shell

I try to make a function which can interrupt the script execution (due to fatal error):

```
quit() {
  echo -e "[ERROR]" | log
  exit 1
}
```

Call example:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    # Do stuff
else
    echo -e "function getValue: wrong parameters" | log
    quit
fi
```

Function `quit` is called (echo in the logfile) but the script keeps going. I've read that `exit` only terminate the subshell (is that true?) which means that it terminates the `quit` function but not the entire script.

For now, I prefer not use return code in `quit` method as it implies a lot of code refactoring.

Is there a way to stop the script from the `quit` function?

**EDIT:**
full example of a case where the error appears:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="./testQuit_log"

quit() {
  echo "quit" | log
  exit 1
}

log() {
  read data
  echo -e "$data" | tee -a "$logfile"
}


foo() {
  if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "foo error" | log
    quit
  fi
  echo "res"
}

rm $logfile

var=`foo p1 p2`
var2=`foo p1`

echo "never echo that!" | log
```

**EDIT2:**
it works correctly when I switch these lines:

```
var=`foo p1 p2`
var2=`foo p1`
```

with

```
var= foo p1 p2
var2= foo p1
```

Any explanation? Is that because of the subshell?

Comment: `exit` will exit the script. The function is not a script. That should work as written. Can you write a short but complete sample that fails to work in the way you are seeing?

Comment: Why are you putting `-e` on all the echos? It's non-portable and does nothing in both the cases you show. (`printf` will interpret C escape sequences in its format string, and is portable. Just remember that unlike echo it does not automatically add a `\n`, so you have to add that to the format if you want it.)

Comment: Question edited. I think I have found the solution, but I'm not quite sure I understand what's happening there...

Comment: The problem is that you use command substitution (with the backticks `\``), and that creates a subshell, so the parent doesn't exit. I don't know a good workaround, if you need to keep the output in a variable. Regarding why edit2 works, you forgot the backticks. Your variable should remain unset.

Comment: Untested, but I guess you could `kill "$PPID"` before the exit. This is a little hacky though. You'd have to make sure you only call `foo()` in a subshell.

Comment: `var=\`foo p1 p2\`` (wrapped in backticks) should throw errors "command foo not found" (or similar), backticks are not quotes. Use `"` double quotes to allow expansion of the contents or `'` single quotes to prevent it. Also, what is `log`? Is there a possibility after you pipe to `log` it doesn't return properly? There is nothing wrong with calling `exit` within a function, so there is something subtle if you are having issues.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: command `foo` will be found because he declared a function named `foo` above.

Comment: Forgive me, I overlooked that completely. Backticks are fine there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it has been outlined in the question's comment section, using `exit` in a subshell will only exit the subshell and it is not easy to work around this limitation. Luckily, exiting from a subshell or even a function in the same shell is not the best idea anyway:

A good pattern to solve the problem of handling an error on a lower level (like a function or subshell) in a language without exceptions is to return the error instead of terminating the program directly from the lower level:

```
foo() {
   if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
       echo "foo error" | log
       return 1
   else
       echo "res"
       # return 0 is the default
   fi
}
```

This allows control flow to return to the highest level even on error, which is generally considered a good thing (and will incredibly ease debugging complex programs). You can use your function like this:

```
var=$( foo p1 p2 ) || exit 1
var2=$( foo p1 ) || exit 1
```

Just to be clear, the `||` branch is not entered if the assignment fails (it won't), but if the command line inside the command substitution (`$( )`) returns a non-zero exit code.

Note that `$( )` should be used for command substitution instead of backticks, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts).

Comment: Got it. I was hoping I can avoid to test anything outside of the `quit` function (and handle all the "quit" stuff at one unique place). Looks like I can't... Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at a debug of the script shows the problem. **var=`foo p1 p2`** forces execution of `foo` in a subshell (**note:** the increase in level from `+` to `++` at the time of the call below) Execution of the script proceeds in a subshell until `exit 1` is reached. `exit 1` effectively exits the subshell returning to the primary script.

```
$ bash -x exitstuck.sh
+ logfile=./testQuit_log
+ rm ./testQuit_log
++ foo p1 p2                # var=`foo p1 p2` enters subshell '+ -> ++'
++ '[' 2 -ne 1 ']'
++ echo 'foo error'
++ log                      # log() called
++ read data
++ echo -e 'foo error'
++ tee -a ./testQuit_log
++ quit                     # quit() called
++ echo quit
++ log
++ read data
++ echo -e quit
++ tee -a ./testQuit_log
++ exit 1                   # exit 1 exits subshell, note: '++ -> +'
+ var='foo error
quit'
++ foo p1
++ '[' 1 -ne 1 ']'
++ echo res
+ var2=res
+ log
+ read data
+ echo 'never echo that!'
+ echo -e 'never echo that!'
+ tee -a ./testQuit_log
never echo that!
```

You can use this to your advantage to accomplish what it is you are trying to do. How? When `exit 1` exits the subshell, it does so returning the exit code `1`. You can test the exit code in your main script and exit as you intend:

```
var=`foo p1 p2`
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    exit
fi
var2=`foo p1`
```

Running in debug again shows the intended operation:

```
$ bash -x exitstuck.sh
+ logfile=./testQuit_log
+ rm ./testQuit_log
++ foo p1 p2
++ '[' 2 -ne 1 ']'
++ echo 'foo error'
++ log
++ read data
++ echo -e 'foo error'
++ tee -a ./testQuit_log
++ quit
++ echo quit
++ log
++ read data
++ echo -e quit
++ tee -a ./testQuit_log
++ exit 1
+ var='foo error
quit'
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ exit
```