# How is it called and what's the exact meaning of issuing a terminal command like $(some command string)?

Tags: terminal, eval

Does the operator

```
$()
```

issued in a terminal window have a specific name?

What's the exact meaning of this operator, I suppose it's a sort of Evaluate... but I'm not sure this is covering all its applications

For instance I know that

```
 cd $(brew --prefix)
```

will evaluate the install path of brew to cd to it

This is the typical question that could be solved by googling but... googling a symbol without knowing the name ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply bash syntax for "command substitution" that specifies that the output of the command inside the $() will be evaluated and then replaced.

So in this case the output from 'brew --prefix' will be returned and added to the cd command.

It is equivalent to the use of backtics. For example:

```
echo `date`
```

There is quite a bit more about [both syntactical options here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts).

Comment: ok but.... no other possible usages applications? does it have a name? doesn't it?

Comment: I updated.  Technically it's referred to as "command substitution".