# I need file size alert script for solaris

Tags: linux, shell, sh, solaris, solaris-10

```
file=/root/stacktrace.log
minsize=100
filesize=$(wc -c <"$file")
echo $filesize
if [ $filesize -ge $minsize ]; then
    mailx -s 'File size is more than 10MB' example@gmail.com < /dev/null
fi
```

Above script is working fine in centos. But its not working in solaris os.

Please help me on this.

Comment: What is not working? And what is the error seen?

Comment: data_file_alert.sh: syntax error at line 3: `filesize=$' unexpected

Comment: How are you running the script? did you specify the interpreter to be invoked explicitly? `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: Using `wc` to get a file size is not very sensible. The filesystem already knows the sizes of your files, so rather than potentially do many 100GB of I/O to your poor disks, just ask the filesystem - `stat`, for example, will tell you. Also, your variable should be called `maxsize` if you think about it a little.

Comment: Hi Inian, I did't specify any interpreter. same script running properly in centos but solaris its not working. whenever iam running this scripts iam getting  syntax error at line 3: `filesize=$' unexpected

Comment: @pradheeppurushothaman How are you starting this script?  If you're using `/bin/sh`, note that Centos (and many other Linux distributions) completely confuse the distinction between POSIX `sh` and `bash`.  Linux `sh` scripts that use non-POSIX "bashisms" will fail on a system such as Solaris where `sh` is standards-compliant.  I suspect `filesize=$(wc -c <"$file")` is just such a "bashism".

Comment: Hi Andrew Thanks for your reply. Iam new  of solaris OS. Can you please tell me. what we can use instead filesize=$(wc -c <"$file")

Comment: @pradheeppurushothaman Since you're apparently running Solaris 10, you may not have the GNU `stat` utility.  You should be able use backticks around `ls -l "$file" | awk '{ print $5 }'` where `$5` means the fifth column of the output of the `ls` command, which should be the size of the file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Can you use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/sh` ?

Comment: thank you so much andrew. its working now

Comment: As @MarkSetchell said: Do not use `wc`. I once had a performance problem when counting files of some Gb. When you do not have `stat` on Solaris, use `find path -name yourfile -size +x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file=/root/stacktrace.log
maxsize=100
if [ -f "$file" ] && [ -n "$(find "$file" -size +"$maxsize"c)" ]; then
    mailx -s "File size is more than $maxsize" example@gmail.com < /dev/null
fi
```

This uses [find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) to determine that the size is `$maxsize` or larger, in this case 100 bytes.  I also required `[ -f "$file" ]` to ensure we're looking at a file rather than a directory so find's recursive search won't find a file inside that directory's structure that is sufficiently large.

[BSD find](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/find/) and [GNU find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Size.html) (but *not* [Solaris find](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7m9j/index.html)) support better units than just `c` for "characters" (bytes).  Try `k`, `M`, or `G` like `-size +"$maxsize"M` or else `-size +$((maxsize*1048576))c`

(Never mind that the syntax highlighting looks odd. You are allowed to nest one level of double quotes inside a `"$(…)"` [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03).)