# Trying to execute "sed" command but getting "command not found" error

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
`sed 's/49%100%/49%!100%/' /etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg`
```

but I'm getting this error

```
-bash: ###############################################################################: command not found
```

If I try to run it without the back ticks, the command will work.

I've tried the following:

```
`sed 's/49%100%/49%!100%/' /etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg` 2>&1

`sed 's/49%100%/49%!100%/' /etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg`> /dev/null
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You are trying to run the output of `sed` as a command - this is expected.  Why do you need the back ticks?

Comment: @codeforester hi, i'm trying to execute this in a shell script, so i'm adding the back ticks.

Comment: You'd need the backticks only if you wanted to do something with the output, like storing it to a variable.

Comment: What do you want to do with the output of the command?  Looks like you wanted to modify your Nagios config file.

Comment: What you're doing with the back-quotes around the `sed` script is telling the shell to execute the output of the `sed` command as if it was a shell script.  It isn't a shell script, so the shell gets unhappy rather quickly.

Comment: @codeforester i'm just trying to modify the content of the configuration.

Comment: Well, your code is trying to *run* the modified configuration as if it were made up of shell commands.

Comment: (well, if we wanted to get really picky, it's trying to string-split and glob-expand the configuration and run that as *one* shell command; [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) goes into why trying to depend on this kind of behavior to run arbitrary commands intentionally doesn't end well).

Answer (score 6):

You don't need back ticks or `$()` to invoke `sed` here since your requirement is not to interpret the output of `sed` as a command.

If your intention is to modify `/etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg`, you could do this:

```
sed 's/49%100%/49%!100%/' /etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg > /etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg.new
```

or, to make an in-place edit (when you are absolutely sure that your `sed` expression is right):

```
sed -i 's/49%100%/49%!100%/' /etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg
```

On BSD systems like macOS, `sed -i` needs an argument.  The command would be:

```
sed -i '' 's/49%100%/49%!100%/' /etc/nagios/objects/services.cfg
```

---

See these posts for more info on back ticks and its more modern form, `$()`:

- [What does backquote backtick mean in commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands)
- [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: `sed -i` is incompatibly different between GNU and BSD implementations -- in the BSD one (including on MacOS X), the argument with a backup filename suffix is mandatory rather than optional (to not have a backup file, one must pass an empty string as a separate argument following `-i`) -- so the code here isn't entirely portable even across systems offering the extension.

Comment: `-i ''`, with the space; `-i''` parses exactly the same as `-i` insofar as the command it's passed to is concerned.

Comment: It's not a bad idea to supply a non-empty argument to `-i` to save the backup, just in case. You can always delete it if the new file looks right. :)

Comment: My preferred method is `sed 's/a/b/' "${file}" > "${file}2" && mv "${file}2" "${file}"` (Same issues as `-i`, and you must be sure that `${file}2` doesn't exist... Learned the habit on Solaris 10 which didn't have a `-i` option at all...)