# Execute a remote script on a local server in Linux using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a script called "test" on a remote server's home folder that contains the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

tengbe=`ifconfig | grep -B1 192.168 | awk 'NR==1 { print $1 }' | sed 's/://g'`
```

Basically, it just stores the name of the interface of the local server into a variable once the script is called. When I ssh into the remote server to call the script, I get an error:

```
ssh remoteserver-IP './test'
./test: line 3: ifconfig: command not found
```

What might be wrong with my script? I have seen various answers that does not offer a solution to my issue.

Comment: The system on which you are running the script does not have `ifconfig` installed, check the output of `which ifconfig`

Comment: By default ifconfig is not in your PATH if you are not root. You are running a remote script on the remote machine. If you want to run a remote script on your local machine, you need to copy it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ ssh remotehost ifconfig
bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

`ifconfig` isn't in your `PATH` on the remote host. You can prove it with:

```
$ which ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig
$ ssh remotehost 'echo $PATH'
(returns lots of dirs, none of which is /sbin)
```

To get around this either specify the full path to ifconfig:

```
$ ssh remotehost /sbin/ifconfig
```

... or configure `$PATH` before calling it:

```
$ ssh remotehost 'PATH=$PATH:/sbin ifconfig'
```

... or edit `$HOME/.bashrc` (or alternatives -- read about your shell's initialisation process) to add `/sbin` to `$PATH` all the time.

For security, in a script it's usually better to specify absolute paths, maybe via variables. So in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFCONFIG=/sbin/ifconfig
tengbe=$(${IFCONFIG} | grep -B1 192.168 | awk 'NR==1 { print $1 }' | sed 's/://g')
```

Note, I've replaced your backticks with `$()` - this isn't required, but it's a good habit to adopt - [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the PATH variable was the trick. Thanks a lot for your solution, it works. I still need to adopt to using the newer model of variable expansion as you have highlighted within your post. Thanks.