# Read the contents of a command into a variable and grab the first line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute a `ps` command for the servers which i'm taking it into an array and take the output of that command into a variable and then take the first line of the content again into a variable. Please find below my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the servers names..."
read -a array
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
content=`ps -auxwww | grep $i`
line=${head -1 content}
echo $line
done
exit 0
```

I'm unable to take the first line from the `$content`. Kindly help on how to extract the first line again into a variable and then display the first line fully. I don't want to create a new file to save the contents. I would like to do it in one go.

Comment: What is `${head -1 content}` supposed to be? `${}` is for wrapping around variables. If you want to get the output of a command, the syntax is `$(command)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly take 1st line from the unix command itself

> content=`ps -auxwww | grep $i | head -1`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one shot, this way:

```
line=$(ps -auxwww | grep -- "$i" | head -1)
```

- it is better to use `$()` instead of back ticks
- `--` will prevent `grep` from failing in case any of your server names starts with a `-`
- it is important to enclose `$i` in double quotes to prevent issues caused by word splitting and globbing (you can use [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) to catch such issues in your script)

If you really want to do it in two steps, then:

```
content=$(ps -auxwww | grep -- "$i")
line=$(head -1 <<< "$content")
```

---

See also:

- [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)