# How to run shell/python script in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm testing my shell script and python script together, so I write a shell script to call these two script in loop like this:

```
while ((1)) ; do
    /usr/local/bin/ovs-appctl dpdk/vhost-list
    sleep 10
    /usr/local/bin/ovs-appctl dpdk/virtio-net-show n-f879ac2f
    sleep 10
    /usr/local/bin/ovs-appctl dpdk/virtio-net-show n-434ab558
    sleep 10
    /usr/local/bin/ovs-appctl dpdk/virtio-net-show i-brpri-p
    sleep 10
    `sh ./env_check`
    `cat output.txt`
    sleep 10
    `python vm_qga_tool /opt/cloud/workspace/servers/6608da87-e374-4796-adb1-8faa29f49e9a/qga.sock connect:172.16.0.1`
    sleep 10
done
```

but the result report error:

```
test-dpdk-virtio-net-show.sh: line 13: Checking: command not found
test-dpdk-virtio-net-show.sh: line 15: {"session":: command not found
```

Line13 is `cat output.txt`, line15 is `python vm_qga_tool ...`.

the output.txt is the result of line12 `sh ./env_check`, and the output of `vm_qga_tool` is like this:

```
{"session"...
```

so how to fix this? How to cat result of the shell script in shell script?

Comment: for an infinite loop, you can use `while :; do <commands here>; done` too

Answer (score 2):

`sh ./env_check` line will be replaced by the output of the script `./env_check`. Current shell will try to execute them as commands. In your case it fails as, **luckily**, bash couldn't interpret them as commands. This could have been a disaster. For example, if your script produced an output like `rm -rf *`, you can imagine what would happen.

If you want to display the result of `./env_check` you have to prepend the line with `echo`, so that the output of `./env_check` will be fed to echo.

```
echo `sh ./env_check`
```

Or if you want to capture the output into a variable you do the following.

```
out=`sh ./env_check`
```

Same goes to `cat ...` and `python ...`

However use of back-ticks is discouraged. Instead use `$(...)`. ([Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts))

```
...
sleep 10
echo $(sh ./env_check)
echo $(cat output.txt)
sleep 10
echo $(python vm_qga_tool /opt/cloud/workspace/servers/6608da87-e374-4796-adb1-8faa29f49e9a/qga.sock connect:172.16.0.1)
sleep 10
...
```

However, you don't need to do any of that anyway. If you don't need to capture the command output, you can directly invoke the scripts, instead of invoking through a sub-shell.

```
...
sleep 10
sh ./env_check
cat output.txt
sleep 10
python vm_qga_tool /opt/cloud/workspace/servers/6608da87-e374-4796-adb1-8faa29f49e9a/qga.sock connect:172.16.0.1
sleep 10
...
```

Comment: You may need to check the return code just after executing the script as `[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "script failed!" && exit 1` to make sure the script returned properly (assuming the script properly handles return codes).

Answer (score 0):

The issues occurred because your shell accepted output of `sh ./env_check` and `python vm_qga_tool ...`  as commands, so it will try to run those commands.
To fix it you should eliminate "`" symbol from`sh ./env_check`or`python vm_qga_tool ...`