# Shell Script Newbie: "Command not found"

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I've been learning shell scripting since yesterday. I want to make a script that returns the minimum number from all the numbers in a text file. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="example.txt"
min=cat $file|head -1
for i in $(cat $file); do
  if [[ $min -gt $i ]]; then
    min=$i
  fi
done
echo $min
```

I keep getting an error in line 3 that says "example.txt: command not found".

Comment: This should get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Chuckling... Stick with it, you will make friends with your shell soon enough. You will want to bookmark [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). A wealth of good information can be found at each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [*command substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
min=$(cat $file|head -1)
```

Besides that, note that the `cat` command is useless here since `head` accepts a filename. It should be:

```
min=$(head -1 "$file")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

add it inside backticks.

```
 min=`cat $file|head -1`
```

Comment: While correct, you should visit the link in the first comment to the original question.