# Using a command that needs backticks to be passed as part of an argument in bash

Tags: linux, bash, hive, escaping

I have a `bash` script like below. Near `table` variable I want to use backticks like in my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -ne 2 ] && { echo "Usage : $0  database table "; exit 1; }

database=$1
table=$2

hive -e "alter table ${database}.`${table}` SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE')"
```

This above script gives me below error

```
script.sh: line 10: table: command not found
```

But if I don't use backticks near table variable then the script works fine.

But I need to have backticks near `table` variable. How can I do that?

I have tried like below as well

```
hive -e "alter table ${database}.$(table) SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE')"
```

I still got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside double quotes, backticks are being interpreted by shell, resulting in `table` being treated as a command.  You need to escape them:

```
hive -e "alter table ${database}.\`${table}\` SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE')"
```

Alternatively, you can use a variable to hold the backticks:

```
bt="\`"
hive -e "alter table ${database}.$bt${table}$bt SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE')"
```

---

The issue with your second command

```
hive -e "alter table ${database}.$(table) SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE')"
```

is that the construct `$(table)` works the same way as `table` inside backticks - it is just a better way of doing command substitution in Bash. Hence you get the same error as earlier.

---

Related posts:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
- [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Backticks in BASH (and other shells) cause the string inside the backticks to be **run as a program**. The **output** of the program is then pasted into the command in place of the backticks.

```
$ echo "it is now `date`"
it is now Wed Jan 31 17:01:28 EST 2018
```

One solution is to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$ echo 'it is now `date`'
it is now `date`
```

However, in your command you want values like ${database} to be evaluated, and single quotes prevent that kind of evaluation as well. So your best bet is to use backslash to escape the backticks:

```
$ echo "it is now \`date\`"
it is now `date`
```

Comment: One can mix multiple quoting types inside a single command or argument. ```echo 'it is now`'"$(date)"'`'``` is perfectly valid: The backticks are literal because they're in single quotes, the `$()` gets expanded because it's in double quotes.

Comment: Great point. Bash syntax is ... amazing. (baroque?) (strange?)