# Why wont some variables echo in the beginning in BASH

Tags: bash, loops, variables, echo

**Here is my full code:**

```
   #!/bin/bash
wget -O /tmp/crex24.txt --no-check-certificate "https://api.crex24.com/CryptoExchangeService/BotPublic/ReturnTicker?request=[NamePairs=BTC_LTC,BTC_ETH,BTC_XMR]"
echo "++++++++++++++++ CREX 24 ++++++++++++++++"
number_of_pairs=`cat /tmp/crex24.txt | grep PairId | wc -l`
count=1
while [ $count -le $number_of_pairs ]
do
pairname=`cat /tmp/crex24.txt | grep -e "PairName" | sed -n "${count}p" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d '", '  | cut -c1-10`
highprice=`cat /tmp/crex24.txt | grep -e "HighPrice" | sed -n "${count}p" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d '", ' | cut -c1-10`
lowprice=`cat /tmp/crex24.txt | grep -e "LowPrice" | sed -n "${count}p" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d '", ' | cut -c1-10`
echo "$highprice $lowprice $pairname"
echo "$pairname $highprice $lowprice"
let "count++"
done
```

**Output:**

```
++++++++++++++++ CREX 24 ++++++++++++++++
0.01663970 0.01574956 BTC_LTC
 0.01663970 0.01574956
0.07105730 0.06700000 BTC_ETH
 0.07105730 0.06700000
0.03130300 0.02700000 BTC_XMR
 0.03130300 0.02700000
```

My question is why wont **$pairname** echo out when in the beginning ?
What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is in the /tmp/crex24.txt file? Looks like ``$pairname`` is just empty.

Comment: The problem is that pairname contains the \r symbol at the end so anything after it will replace it on the line.

Comment: @huz_akh what do you want the output to actually look like?

Comment: Also, don't use backticks for subshell, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Kokogino : No its not empty as you can see in the above live
PTRK : I am not aware of the \r , I will look more into it
ffledgling : I want $pairname in the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that pairname contains the character \r as shown with `bash -x script.sh`

```
+ pairname=$'BTC_XMR\r'
```

Since you used echo without -e, this should not be a problem but i dont know why, echo process this escape character and so anything after that is returned to the first character of the line and covers pairname.

My answer is to use `cut -d` instead of `cut -c` to get pairname

```
pairname=$(cat /tmp/crex24.txt | grep -e "PairName" | sed -n "${count}p" | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d\" -f2)
```

gives you

```
++++++++++++++++ CREX 24 ++++++++++++++++
0.01663970 0.01574956 BTC_LTC
BTC_LTC 0.01663970 0.01574956
0.07105730 0.06700000 BTC_ETH
BTC_ETH 0.07105730 0.06700000
0.03130300 0.02700000 BTC_XMR
BTC_XMR 0.03130300 0.02700000
```

Now we have pairname in the beginning

Comment: i need output to only 8 decimals, that is why I used cut -c

Comment: Does pairname needs to be 8 character long also ?

Comment: I dont think so , thats optional. Thanks for the debug command of `bash -x` and the \r. Learned something new.