# Check if a specific argument is missing - order not important

Tags: bash

What is the easiest (and possibly one-liner) way to check for the absence of a specific argument in a bash script, disregarding the argument order ?

I would like to assign at the beginning of the script a "boolean" variable named `REAL_RUN` with `true` or `false` based on the absence or presence of an argument `--dry-run` included among all the script arguments. Something like this:

```
REAL_RUN=... # <-- what to put here ?
if [ "$REAL_RUN" = true ] ; then
   # do something
fi
```

I expect `REAL_RUN` to be assigned `true` with the following cases:

```
./run.sh
./run.sh foo bar
./run.sh foo --dry-run-with-unexpected-suffix bar
./run.sh foo ------dry-run bar
```

Instead, with the following examples `REAL_RUN` must be set to `false`

```
./run.sh --dry-run
./run.sh foo --dry-run
./run.sh --dry-run bar
./run.sh foo --dry-run bar
```

Answer (score 1):

`case` is portable to POSIX `sh`. It *can* be a one-liner, though conventionally, the statement is divided over multiple physical lines.

```
case " $@ " in *\ --dry-run\ *) REAL_RUN=false;; *) REAL_RUN=true;; esac
```

or for legibility

```
# Put spaces around "$@" to make the later logic simpler
case " $@ " in
  # If --dry run exists with spaces on both sides,
  *\ --dry-run\ *)
    # Set REAL_RUN to false
    REAL_RUN=false;;
  # Otherwise,
  *)
    # ... it's true.
    REAL_RUN=true;;
esac
```

Some people like to put the special token `;;` on a line of its own but in a simple `case` like this, that seems excessive.

This is slightly inexact in that it fails to distinguish between spaces between arguments and quoted spaces.  Somebody could write `command " --dry-run "` and it would trigger the condition, even though strictly speaking, this should be interpreted as a static string argument which starts and ends with a literal space, and not an option at all.  (To prevent this, probably loop over `"$@"` and check for a literal argument:

```
REAL_RUN=true
for arg; do    # shorthand for 'for arg in "$@"; do'
    case $arg in
      --dry-run) REAL_RUN=false;;
    esac
done
```

but this definitely isn't a one-line any longer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex matching in `BASH`:

```
[[ $# -eq 0 || ! $* =~ (^| )--dry-run( |$) ]] &&
REAL_RUN=true || REAL_RUN=false;

echo "REAL_RUN=$REAL_RUN"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a function like :

```
contains () {
  local e match="$1"
  shift
  for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 0 ; done
  return 1
}
```

And then use it by passing the array already coming from the system :

```
[[ `contains "apple" "$@"` -eq 0 ]] && echo "Is present" || echo "Is not present"
```

Regards!

Comment: The command substitution captures the function's standard output, not its return code (and you should aveid the obsolescent backticks syntax). The proper way to use this is much simpler: `contains "apple" "$@" && echo "Is present" || echo "Is not present"`

Comment: @tripleee one question , why is the use of backticks obsolete? I always understood the backticks like a substitution happening in the same process while the $() forks into a new process. Is that the case?

Comment: No, they are basically equivalent, though some details of their parsing differs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts

Comment: @tripleee ok. got it now. Thanks!