# Bash: echo showing blank value

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two variables as follows

```
SampleOutput=`some command giving output`
Status=`echo "$SampleOutput" | grep -qs "Active"`
echo $SampleOutput
echo $Status
```

Here `$SampleOutput` has value as `AgentEnable=Active bla bla bla`

However, `$Status` is coming as `blank` I am not sure why `$Status` is coming as blank when it should have value `AgentEnable=Active`

Comment: I recommend you read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Did you consider executing `echo "$SampleOutput" | grep -qs "Active"` on its own to see what its output is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `grep -q` you don't get any output from `grep`. Only return status is available that you can get using:

```
grep -qs "Enable" <<< "$SampleOutput"
Status=$?
```

As per `man grep`:

> `-q, --quiet, --silent`
>   **Quiet mode:** suppress normal output.  grep will only search a file until a match has been found, making searches potentially less expensive.

Note that if you are not using `SampleOutput` anywhere else then you can directly use:

```
some command | grep -qs "Enable"
Status=$?
```