# Unable to assign env variable using a command's output

Tags: bash, zsh

I can set environment variables like this.

```
➤ foo=bar env | grep foo
foo=bar
```

But, what if, I can only get `foo=bar` string after I execute a command (which is my use-case). The simplest way to emulate this is using a simple `echo` command.

```
➤ `echo foo=bar` env | grep foo
zsh: command not found: foo=bar
```

In this, zsh/bash starts interpreting it as a command. How do I fix this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: FWIW, I find this question very clear.  I think it's a good example of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the shell looks for the form `var1=val1 var2=val2 ... command` before doing expansions, including command substitution (`` `...` `` or `$(...)`).

One way to work around the problem is to use `eval` to cause the shell to do its parsing after the command substitution is done:

```
eval "$(echo foo=bar)" env | grep foo
```

(See [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449778/4154375) for an explanation of why I've changed `` `...` `` to `$(...)`.)

Unfortunately, `eval` is potentially dangerous.  It should not be used unless there is no other alternative.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Another alternative is to use `export` in a subshell.  One way is:

```
{ export "$(echo foo=bar)" ; env ; } | grep foo
```

Since the `export` is done in a pipeline (and not the last part of a pipeline, which would make a difference for some shells or some modes) it doesn't affect the variable settings in the current shell.  If the command is not in a pipeline, then it would be necessary to explicitly run it in a subshell to get the same effect.  E.g.

```
( export "$(echo foo=bar)" ; env ) > tmpfile
grep foo tmpfile
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me as expected. Have you tried like below?

```
env `echo foo=bar` | grep foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but try this:

```
$ echo "hello" && foo=bar env | grep foo
hello
foo=bar
```