# Bash, how to create an array in one line of code

Tags: bash

how can I create an array in one step instead of two stages, like shown below?' 
The example below was executed on a live Linux system.

```
POSITION=`volt |grep ate |awk '{print $4}'` #returns three integers 
declare -a POSITION_ARRAY=($POSITION)  #create an array
```

Comment: Could some one explain what `volt` and `grep ate` are? Does `ate` represent switches or is it input?

Comment: @Dunois I don't know what `volt` is, but `volt | grep ate` means that grep searches the output of `volt` for lines containing `ate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate variable, as wjandrea said. These two snippets are equivalent:

```
POSITION=$(volt | grep ate | awk '{print $4}')
declare -a POSITION_ARRAY=($POSITION)
```

```
# declare -a also works, but isn't needed in modern Bash
POSITION_ARRAY=( $(volt | grep ate | awk '{print $4}') )
```

If you know the output of the pipeline is witespace-delimited integers this will do what you want. But it [*isn't a safe way to populate an array*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) from arbitrary command output, because [unquoted expansions will be word-split and globbed](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

The proper way to read a command's output into an array, split by lines, is with the [`readarray` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray), like so:

```sh
readarray -t POSITION_ARRAY < <(volt | grep ate | awk '{print $4}')
```

Comment: Note: `readarray` is a bash v4 feature, so if you’re running bash v3 (macOS says hi!), it won’t be available.

Comment: True, the [Bash Pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) entry I linked to has a pattern for Bash 3 users.

Comment: If you're going to use an unquoted command substitution where you want to apply word splitting, I recommend using `set -f` to disable file name generation (globbing)

Comment: There's a lot of hoops you have to jump through to make unquoted expansions "work"; it's much, much safer to just properly-quote variables and other expansions.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put the command in the parentheses.

By the way, `declare -a` is not needed, and [backticks are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449778/4518341) in favour of `$()`.

```
POSITION_ARRAY=( $(volt | grep ate | awk '{print $4}') )
```

And FWIW you can merge the grep and AWK commands:

```
POSITION_ARRAY=( $(volt | awk '/ate/ {print $4}') )
```