# How does this work to count number of lines in a file? no_of_lines=`<$file wc -l`

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection, wc

I can almost undestand why

```
no_of_lines=`wc -l <$file`
```

stores the number of lines in file. But how does

```
no_of_lines2=`<$file wc -l`
```

also give the same answer?

Comment: Please take a look at [benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

**Shell trivia:** Redirections don't have to come after commands. That's where people usually put them, but they can actually be anywhere—at the end, at the beginning, or even in the middle.

These are all equivalent:

```
wc -l <file
<file wc -l
wc <file -l
```