# Anyone can explain why the outputs are different?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

As per the below outputs, look like only ZONES1 is array, the other two are string, why?

```
$ ZONES0=$(aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region ap-southeast-2  --query AvailabilityZones[*].ZoneId[] --output text)

echo ${ZONES0[0]}
apse2-az3 apse2-az1 apse2-az2


$ ZONES1=(`aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region ap-southeast-2    --query AvailabilityZones[*].ZoneId[] --output text`)

$echo ${ZONES1[0]}
$ apse2-az3

$ ZONES2=$(aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region ap-south-1 | jq -r '.AvailabilityZones[].ZoneId')

$echo ${ZONES2[0]}
 aps1-az1 aps1-az3 aps1-az2
```

[screenshot of the codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJXTs.jpg)

If I run

```
ZONES0=( $(aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region ap-southeast-2  --query AvailabilityZones[*].ZoneId[] --output text) ).
```

the output is below

```
$ echo $ZONES0
apse2-az3
$ echo $ZONES0[0]
apse2-az3[0]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlxXu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`ZONES1` is array because in bash arrays can be defined using a [compound assignments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) of the form:

```
name=(value1 value2 … )
```

So your expression returns `apse2-az3 apse2-az1 apse2-az2` which is placed in the `(...)` to declare an array.

If you want to do the same for `ZONES0`, you just place in the compound assignment:

```
ZONES0=( $(aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region ap-southeast-2  --query AvailabilityZones[*].ZoneId[] --output text) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  To make it clear, I attached a screenshot

Comment: @tiger06 Hi. The backtick you marked  s [command substitiution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) is similar to `$(...)`. You can read more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  To make it clear, I attached a screenshot. in ZONES1, there is ` in the parentheses. What is its purpose?

Comment: @tiger06 Its [command subsitiotion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).