# Simple sql script fails on execution

Tags: sql, bash, oracle

Below is a sample bash script and it seems to error out when i execute the bash. The sql works on its own but in a script oddly.

Please advise

> - JOB_RUNNING='SELECT count(1) from gv b,gv a WHERE b.paddr = a.addr AND type='''USER''' AND b.status='''ACTIVE''' AND
>   b.program='''Thin Client'''
>   * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'

```
JOB_RUNNING=`sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET HEADING OFF;
SELECT count(1) from gv\$session b,gv\$process a WHERE b.paddr = a.addr AND type='USER' AND b.status='ACTIVE' AND b.program='Thin Client';
 exit;
EOF
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output shows `from gv b,gv a` so the `$` is still being treated as a shell variable.

[From BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082):

> Backslashes (\) inside backticks are handled in a non-obvious manner ...

Either double-escape those:

```
JOB_RUNNING=`sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET HEADING OFF;
SELECT count(1) from gv\\$session b,gv\\$process a WHERE b.paddr = a.addr AND type='USER' AND b.status='ACTIVE' AND b.program='Thin Client';
 exit;
EOF
`
```

or use `$()` instead of backticks:

```
JOB_RUNNING=$(sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET HEADING OFF;
SELECT count(1) from gv\$session b,gv\$process a WHERE b.paddr = a.addr AND type='USER' AND b.status='ACTIVE' AND b.program='Thin Client';
 exit;
EOF
)
```

See also: [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449778/266304)

Comment: thank you Alex. It was just as simple as that. You are a star