# Execute a Response of a command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the following script the response of `sed` is

```
export SECRET_KEY= '321321
```

I need to execute that response in the shell, exporting the value to SECRET_KEY i.e. `echo $SECRET_KEY` will give the exported key as `321321`

```
aws-runas test >>test.txt
echo `sed -n -e 's/^.*\(\(export SECRET_KEY\).*\)/\1/p' test.txt`
```

I've tried using `eval`, `source <(echo $command)`. it gives the following error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command

Is there a way to execute the response of `sed` as a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use sed:

```sh
`sed -n -e 's/^.*\(\(export SECRET_KEY\).*\)/\1/p' test.txt`
```

Be careful, the export that you made doesn't work.

```sh
export SECRET_KEY= '321321'
export: not an identifier: 321321
```

Use:

```sh
export SECRET_KEY=321321
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `$( )` instead of backticks -- escaping in backticks is a bit weird, and while this particular command happens not to trigger any of the weirdness, it's best to just avoid backticks altogether. See [BashFAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts).